# BDD testing REST/JSON-RPC API

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, testing, bdd

I work on a project which uses a mix of REST and JSON-RPC back-end API for mobile apps. Application servers are built on node.js (express, cluster, pm2) + redis (ioredis) + mysql (node-mysql) + rabbitmq (amqp). Now we face a heavy refactoring, but there are no tests! Undoubtedly, it's a huge trouble :(

In the beginning, we planned to cover it with BDD tests. It sounds quite easy, but there is one obstacle, preparing the environment before tests start. For instance, some tests change data in storage and we have to reload the database dump every time. Frankly, it is extremely inconvenient. Moreover, keeping it in actual (up-to-date) condition isn't easy, e.g. when I change the code, I have to change the dump too.

So, I'm interested in ways/tools/paradigms which can be used for preparing the state (content) of data storage (MySQL and Redis).

Thank you in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: You need to elaborate this question with regard to your test architecture, specifically how each part is deployed and what sort of access your test suite has to the back-end server if any.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fun things about the "Given / When / Then" template that most BDD tools use is that the behaviour is caused by the "When", not the "Given". So, it doesn't matter how the "Given" is set up.

A lot of people use the real tools to set up the Given, but it doesn't have to be that way.

You can set up the "Given" using existing standard data. For instance, I might say, "Given an article about the Zika crisis..." If you're working on a newspaper site right now, you'll have a lot of articles. You can check to make sure there is one, and even use this step to store the article ID that you're expecting to see in the next steps. You can set up some "default data" that gives you this article. It's OK to check whether there is one, and if there isn't, make one (as long as it always leaves the database in a consistent state for the next scenarios - don't rely on one scenario running after another!)

Even if you make changes to the default data, you can always reset those changes in your "AfterScenario" hooks. JBehave, Cucumber and SpecFlow all have these, [as does Cucumber.js](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/docs/cucumber-tck/environment-hooks).

If you need to set up something different each time, try appending a datetimestamp to the names that are used. For instance, the account isn't created by Mr North, it's created by Mr North20160202224400. That way you'll always have unique IDs. You can use this in combination with the "after" hooks to make sure you're cleaning up the right thing, too.

Don't be afraid to use the "background" data, which can be set up for each scenario in place of "default" data. And remember that you can just make simple SQL calls for these; you don't have to go through any UI.

Lastly, look at the [page object pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html). It's intended to replicate the behaviour of a web page and to abstract away the actual button clicks, but you should be able to see parallels between this and abstracting away the behaviour that creates different pieces of data. I like to think in terms of capabilities: "What can I do with this service / web page / API?" That helps me to form the PageObject. This will also help you to isolate the behaviour of data creation so that when it does change, it only changes in one place.

Without more context it's hard to know which of these approaches is right for you, but all of these things - the "I don't care how" approach to Givens, the background data, the "AfterScenario" hooks, and the PageObject pattern - were created to solve the kind of problems you're facing.

Comment: We use MochaJS for tests and use `beforeEach` hooks for load SQL files into MySQL and fill Redis for preparing storage state for each test. As I said above, it's comfortless, e.g. when I add only one field to entity's model, I have to change: some SQL files, some Redis files and test code. I do hope that at least one tool exists in the world for automating that process. Undoubtedly, we are able to write own bicycle and we have ideas how to it does work, but I extremely dislike re-inventing of a bicycle.

Comment: Have you looked at the Builder pattern? It's a common way to create the kind of entities you're talking about. It would replace the SQL files with code, which is usually easier to maintain. You can set it up with defaults so that if a scenario doesn't care about the field you change nothing.